# If you use the git diff command, how do you get out of that mess?

Tags: git

I'm trying to use Git, within a Git Bash terminal-window on MS Windows 8.1

When I enter: `$git diff file1`
to see the changes in a given file, it then presents me with a `:` prompt.

How does one get out of that mode, short of closing the whole terminal-window and starting over again?
I tried CTRL-C (many times), etc. very annoying!

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Edit your `.gitconfig` file and set `tool` to be the tool you want to compare with.

Comment: q = quit; f = forward; b = backward.

Comment: @r---------k yeah.. I hate those mandatory spaces as well.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: It's not the diff tool, it's the pager. You'll see the same thing with `git log`.

Comment: VERY annoying..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get away from the `:` prompt, type `q`.

`git diff`, like many git commands, pipes its output through a pager by default. The default pager is typically `less`, and the `less` command uses `:` as its default prompt.

You should see the same thing for `git log` and so forth.

Type `man less` at your shell prompt to learn how to use the `less` command. Quick summary:

- Space to go forward a page
- `b` to go back a page
- `d` to go forward half a page
- `u` to go back half a page
- up and down arrows (or `k` and `j`) to go up and down a line at a time
- `q` to quit
- `h` for help.

You can configure the `less` command (see the above mentioned man page for details). You can also configure which pager `git` users for commands that produce a lot of output if you'd rather not use `less`.

Personally, I have the `$GIT_PAGER` environment variable set to `cat`, so it effectively doesn't use a pager at all; I pipe it through `less` manually if I want to. But you might find it more convenient to let `git` do that for you.

Comment: Thank you Keith - you have enlightened me!  I was feeling really frustrated.

Answer (score 4):

To get out of the pager, one can press <kbd>q</kbd>.

In fact there are several other commands too, see the list [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).